# Acumulated SUM of nodes/successors (Excel)

Tags: excel, tree, sum, circular-dependency

Trying to get an accumulated sum in column based on the sum successors(nodes) of that given node (for each predecesors), like the next image:

[image].

**Where** "Nod to SUM" is the description of which values to SUM.

Im looking if there is a more effective way than my forced solution (which cant scale up, cant get empty values and uses a semi-circular dependency), posted in the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

By far after days trying to make it work i was able to do it (with a main difference that when req column is not emply the result doesnt consider that row value to the SUM)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY4Uy.png)

But with a really sturdy and fixed way like the following example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(Mall[nod],O2:O27,$K$2:$K$11))+IF(Mall[@req]<>"",0,Mall[@[dist m]]) 
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(Mall[nod],P2:P27,$K$2:$K$11))+IF(Mall[@req]<>"",0,Mall[@[dist m]])
```

**Where:**

- ($K$2:$K$11) is the column containing the acumulated sums (the previous formula but different on each row based on the next criteria)
- Criteria: (O2:O27 and P2:P27 are arrays "{ }" obtaining the nodes where the current node row appears like: for A:{B} or B:{C,RP1}
  using ctrl shift enter.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Mall[nod],IFERROR(SMALL(IF(Mall[predecesor]=O1,ROW(Mall[predecesor])-1),ROW()-1),"")),"")`

the problem here is when the table named "Mall" have emply rows the whole formula(sumproduct also [producing 0s at the search of nodes(O2:O27 P2:P27)]) doesnt work and returns 0 (at $K$2:$K$11).